# insert into specified location of a json array

Tags: javascript, json

In the following js variable I have my json data;
I am getting the json data through a session;

```
var  newVariable=(document.getElementById("populateDT").innerHTML);
```

which is the following.

```
 var newVariable=[
        {
            "Identifier": "0",
            "Label": "abc",
            "Categories": "Standard",
            "UpdatedBy": "Lno",
            "UpdatedAt": "13",
            "RefId": "0",
            "Edit": "0",
            "Cs": [
                "99",
                "13"
            ],
            "ActionMessage": "Form",
            "Message": "asfdasf",
            "Combiner": []
        },
        {
            "Identifier": "1",
            "Label": "abc",
            "Categories": "Standard",
            "UpdatedBy": "Lno",
            "UpdatedAt": "01",
            "RefId": "0",
            "Edit": "1",
            "Cs": [
                "05",
                "213"
            ],
            "ActionMessage": "Form",
            "Message": "asfdasf",
            "Combiner": []
        }
    ];
```

then I am doing this 
`newVariable[jsonArrayNum]=toReplace;` // toReplace is globally declared

to replace is the following.

```
 var toReplace={
    "Identifier": "0",
    "Label": "Critical",
    "Categories": "Standard",
    "UpdatedBy": "Lno",
    "UpdatedAt": "13",
    "RefId": "0",
    "Edit": "0",
    "Cs": [
        "205",
        "992"
    ],
    "ActionMessage": "Form",
    "Message": "abcd",
    "Combiner": []
};
```

But it doesnt seem to replace the first location with the new json field. I am getting the old json array.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, there must be something else going on. Were there any errors thrown?

Comment: Works for me. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAbSH/)

Comment: That's JavaScript not JSON...

Comment: no errors thrown.. but on when I do this console.log(newVariable[0]); 
I get blank data.

Comment: @user2415379 Can you show more of your code?

Comment: ok thanks. I should be doing something else wrong..

Answer (score -1):

I would use the array functions:

```
newVariable.shift();
newVariable.unshift(toReplace);
```

Comment: Why would you use those functions rather than just setting the value like he is doing? This makes no sense, and only allows you to modify the first element anyways.

Comment: Because he wanted the first element of the array changed and replaced. Also for any reasons the proto of the array is changed the first key might not be 0. The above way is the correct way to remove first element from a array and add a new element at the start of it.

Comment: He doesn't need to remove the element. He only wants to modify it. I wouldn't call this correct at all. It's unnecessary. How would you replace say element 4?

Comment: element 4 or the 4th element in the array?

Comment: I'm saying imagine if he wanted to simply replace the 4th element in an array of n > 4 elements. This method wouldn't work for that purpose.

Comment: If supposing I wanted to replace the second element in the array then how would I do it through this function?

Comment: First thats not what he wanted, second the 4th element of a array doesn't necessarily is key 4;

var testing = Array();
testing[0] = 1;
testing[10] = 1;
testing[30] = 1;
testing[100] = 1;

testing[4] > undefined in that case but the 4th element is key 100 so don't think that key = element number.
Also to answer your question in that case you use array slice. However this is simpler for first element replacement.

Comment: Could you give me an example of array slice wherein you have to delete the first element. consider location 0 of the array and insert into that same location.
asking only because I did try doing that. It does not give the correct result for the first location.